# how to select dynamically in select * from <table_name> partiton (Partition name)?

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

i have a big table with several partition. my partition name is like below:

```
P_13931203
P_13931204
P_13931205
P_13931206
```

i have a select for create partition name dynamically as below:

```
select 'P_' || to_char(sysdate-1,'yyyymmdd','nls_calendar=persian') from dual;
example Output: P_13931204
```

when i select as below everything is OK:

```
select *
from <table_name> partition (P_13931205);
```

but when i select as below i get error:

```
select *
from <table_name> partition (select 'P_' || to_char(sysdate-1,'yyyymmdd','nls_calendar=persian') from dual);
```

error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 2 Column: 28
>   syntax error, expected :
>   identifier

Comment: Why don't you use a `where` clause that selects the right partition? The optimizer is generally pretty good at partition pruning in this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
select * from partition 
(select 'P_' || to_char( sysdate-1,'yyyymmdd','nls_calendar=persian') from dual
) Dummy_table;
```

Beacuse after every sub-query select you have to mention a dataset name.