# How to select from partition while concatenating its name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, partition

I have the same problem like this one:
[how to select dynamically in select * from <table_name> partiton (Partition name)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739994/how-to-select-dynamically-in-select-from-table-name-partiton-partition-name) but in Mysql.

When using:

```
select concat('p', year(now()), month(now()));
```

Response is:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| concat('p', year(now()), month(now())) |
+----------------------------------------+
| p20153                                 |
+----------------------------------------+
```

When trying to use:

```
select max(ttime) from table partition(select concat('p', year(now()), month(now()))));
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select concat('p', year(now()), month(now()))))' at line 1
```

of course when trying `select max(ttime) from table partition(p20153)` works as expected:

```
root@localhost [tom]> select max(ttime) from table partition(p20153);
+---------------------+
| max(ttime)          |
+---------------------+
| 2015-03-16 09:54:34 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice the dynamic part is the partition name and not the table name.
Sample data:

```
root@localhost [tom]> select id, ttime, value from table partition(p20153) limit 10;
+----------+---------------------+----------+
| id       | ttime               | value    |
+----------+---------------------+----------+
| 13964275 | 2015-03-01 00:05:11 | 16450824 |
| 13964291 | 2015-03-01 00:08:12 | 15964352 |
| 13964332 | 2015-03-01 00:09:42 | 14701984 |
| 13964379 | 2015-03-01 00:13:27 |    26128 |
| 13964411 | 2015-03-01 00:16:29 | 11073744 |
| 13964452 | 2015-03-01 00:20:34 | 14747992 |
| 13964486 | 2015-03-01 00:23:35 |   177800 |
| 13964507 | 2015-03-01 00:26:36 | 16786408 |
| 13964542 | 2015-03-01 00:28:28 |  8749552 |
| 13964571 | 2015-03-01 00:31:30 | 16932344 |
+----------+---------------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: please Edit your Question and add Expected output as well as sample data

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not clean but it worked (my case is creating a new partition with dynamic name). In your case, using SET to create variables for partition name as well as query.

```
SET @pt= concat('p', year(now()), month(now()));

SET @query = concat('select max(ttime) from table partition(', @pt, ')');
```

You can confirm partition name and query syntax by:

```
SELECT @pt, @query;
```

Now execute your query:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score -1):

The Syntax you are using in your query is not right try this

```
select max(ttime) from 
(
  select concat('p', year(now()), month(now())) as ttime 
)
temp
```

Comment: Not sure how this query helps as ttime will get the partition name and I just select max of one value. I think I've mislead you, I've added sample data and expected result to the question.